# how to not use inline js events?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am used to using inline events in my websites for example

```
<head>
<script>
function func() {
alert("test");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv" onclick="func()"></div>
</body>
```

I noticed that sites these days do not use inline events at all. I know you can set events pragmatically like:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').onclick = function(){ func()}
```

Is this how it should be done? Do I have to put the above line at the end of every page?

How are the keypress,click, and blur events attached to the input fields on this site for example: https://twitter.com/signup

Thanks.

Comment: @SomethVictory how ironic ... you have asked 5 questions and only accepted an answer on 1 of them ....

Comment: That's because I've never got a correct answer! till now, I still could get. Have you seen anyone answer my question correctly and I didn't accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to add event listeners is to use the built in methods :

```
var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
if (el.addEventListener) {
  el.addEventListener('click', modifyText, false); 
} else if (el.attachEvent)  {
  el.attachEvent('onclick', modifyText);
}

function modifyText() {

}
```

This promotes cleaner more readable and reusable code. (Note `attachEvent` is for pre IE9)

You can either place this code at the end of the `<body>` tag (or anywhere within the `<body>` tag but after the DOM element is added) or within a [window `onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) function - which executes after the DOM has completed loading :

```
window.onload = function() {  
  // here
};
```

Comment: I would have to place this chunk of code at the end of each page for every event?

Comment: @user969622 updated my answer - either at the bottom or within the window.onload function

Comment: This is indeed cleaner in that it allows for multiple bindings on the same event, but without abstracting the different browser apis for the bind, I would argue that you're _worse_ off this way. Use an abstraction like jQuery, mootools, etc...

Comment: @user969622 yes ... see line 96 to 101 -> https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is one valid way to add an event to an object, but it prevents more than one function from being bound at a time.

I would recommend looking into jQuery (or similar javascript library, like mootools), which is how the vast majority of sites bind their javascript events these days.

For example, in jQuery you generally bind clicks like this:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function(event) {
  // click handling code
});
```

Comment: This answer, because it points out the problem of `onclick` property.

Answer (score 0):

The prefered method is to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), often in combination with a library (such as [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/) or [jQuery](http://jQuery.com)) that smooths over variations between browsers (e.g. old-IE not supporting `addEventListener`).

> Do I have to put the above line at the end of every page?

Usually you would put JavaScript in a file of its own, and then `src` it into each page that needed it.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea here is that the DOM element that you want to register the handler on should be loaded. so either you do the event binding after the element html, or you could do it in the window.onload event handler, which could be defined before the actual tag definition, like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
 // your event binding
}
```

But my advice would be to include javascript at the end of the document as much as possible.